# Why sw instruction in mips using byte as offset unit?

Tags: encoding, mips, offset, mips32, instruction-set

I have a question about the offset units used in MIPS32 instructions. I just noticed that memory access instructions like `lw $t0, offset($s1)` has `offset` of unit **byte**, while branching instructions like `beq $r1, $r2, L1` and jump `j SOMEWHERE` both have unit **word**.

IIRC, MIPS requires that every data/instructions should be stored **aligned** in memory at address of multiple of 4, i.e. `0x0, 0x4, 0x8, ... etc`. If this is true, then why not let `offset` in `lw/sw` of unit **word**, so the range is larger? Is this because of `lb/sb` which uses a byte unit? So <del>*Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules*</del> *["] Good design demands good compromises.[."]* applies here?

I also wonder what will happen if I use `lw` to load data that is at address that is not a multiple of 4?

Comment: The second part of your question is answered in the reference from MIPS / Imagination: _"If either of the 2 least-significant bits of the address is non-zero, an Address Error exception occurs."_

Comment: Dynamically-typed languages often use "must be zero" bits as tags for runtime type checking. For example, you might say "If it's a string, then add 2 to the pointer." To access the string, you do `lw $s0,-2($t0)`. If `$t0` really is a string, then the `-2` in the offset cancels the `+2` in the pointer and the load succeeds. If not, you get a processor exception, and you can convert that to a runtime error. Basically, you let the hardware do the type checking for you.

Comment: @RaymondChen: That's really interesting!

Comment: I never would have thought to use alignment errors as a form of type checking. That's very clever!